# NSNotificationCenter Observer Not Receiving Notification

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I am aware of the standard reasons as to why a notification would not be received:

- Deallocating or nullifying the registered object.
- Removing the object as an observer.
- Not registering as an observer.
- Registering for the wrong notification or posting the wrong notification.

I can happily say that I am damn sure that none of these are happening. I suppose the most likely is that the object is at some point being nullified and recreated, but it registers for the notification upon initialisation.

Here is where I register:

```
/**
 *  initialises an object with a unique file url
 *
 *  @param  url                         the url to set as the file url
 */
- (id)initWithFileURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if (self = [super initWithFileURL:url])
    {
        self.entries                    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //  we want to be notified when a note has changed
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(noteChanged)
                                                     name:@"com.andbeyond.jamesvalaitis.notesChanged"
                                                   object:self];

        NSLog(@"Just registered for 'com.andbeyond.jamesvalaitis.notesChanged'");
    }

    return self;
}
```

Here is where I post the notification:

```
/**
 *  save the note content
 */
- (void)saveNote
{
    if (_isChanged)
    {
        //  save to the text view to the note's contents
        self.note.noteContent           = self.noteView.text;

        //  post a notification that we changed the notes
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"com.andbeyond.jamesvalaitis.notesChanged" object:nil];

        NSLog(@"Just posted 'com.andbeyond.jamesvalaitis.notesChanged'");

        //  make sure we know it's already saved
        _isChanged                          = NO;
    }
}
```

This is the method that is not being called:

```
/**
 *  called when a note has changed
 */
- (void)noteChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Just received for 'com.andbeyond.jamesvalaitis.notesChanged'");

    //  save the notes
    [self saveToURL:self.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
    {
        if (success)
            NSLog(@"Note updated.");
    }];
}
```

This is the console clarifying that I both register and post the notification:

> 2012-11-15 13:27:50.958 iCloud Custom[11269:907] Just registered for
>   'com.andbeyond.jamesvalaitis.notesChanged'
>
> 2012-11-15 13:28:24.184 iCloud Custom[11269:907] Just posted
>   'com.andbeyond.jamesvalaitis.notesChanged'

[The whole project can be found here.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25868753/iCloud%20Custom.zip)

Comment: Add the noteChanged method to the post...

Comment: your selector is still like this @selector(noteChanged) .. then how will it call this - (void)noteChanged:(NSNotification *)notification ??? you need to change your selector like this @selector(noteChanged:)

Comment: @DineshRaja: Hi Dinesh and James, I am facing a similar issue and having been through all the answers on this post, applying the suggestions; still things haven't worked out for me.
I am able to post the Notification successfully and declare the Observer as well. But the logic where the check is made doesn't gets executed.
How should I share the code? Or should I post a rather duplicate question?

Comment: @ArchitKapoor You can post a new question with your code or put a code on gist/pastebin and share link here. We could help you then.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think I have figured out the answer. You are creating the notification in `UIDocument` file named `NotesDocument.m` . So when you create an observer, you set the object as `self`. That means the NotesDocument object . But when you `post the notification`, you are sending the object as `nil`. So `it wont observe the notification` as per documentation. **Easy way to overcome this is you need set object as `nil` when creating a notification. Otherwise you need to pass an `NotesDocument Object`.**

Check out the below image and parameter details for the addObserver method of notification.

[image]

check out the `notificationSender` parameter .The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, **only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.**

Comment: What an idiot I have been. I totally didn't mean to set the object as self when I registered for the notification.

This works perfectly now.

Thank you so damn much.

Comment: I just had the exact same issue, and can't believe I found the answer so quickly. This is such a tiny thing; so easy to overlook and so difficult to spot. Thank you very much.

Comment: About 20 minutes spent thinking I had `nil` as the object ini the observer, and it was `self`. Thank you for this post to trigger me to check what I expected the pink-colored property to be correct. :)

Comment: Had the same thing in Swift 3, though my case was mistakenly defining notification name when adding an observer. Your answer helped =)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
...
selector:@selector(noteChanged:) 

...
- (void) noteChanged:(NSNotification *) notification
...
```

Comment: Just made this change, and it did not work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Try using a static string in both places instead of a different string for the notification. They appear to be exactly the same, but there could be something odd.

Answer (score -6):

The following url will solve your problem.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_nsnotificationcenter

Comment: I have used NSNotificationCenter a lot and am aware of the process of implementing it. You adamance that your link would help me is quite respectable, but sadly mistaken.